# Sum of normal random variables being not normal

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If X and Y are identically distributed as $N(0,1)$ (but not independent) with covariance $cov(X, Y)=\frac{1}{2}$ (and these are the only constraints). Is it possible to construct X and Y such that X+Y is not normally distributed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sure. Take $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and then define $Y$ by $Y=X$ if $|X|>a$ and $Y = -X$ for $|X|<a$ (so basically you flip the center part around. Then we get:
$$ \mathrm{cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm E((X-0)(Y-0)) = \mathrm E(XY) = \int_{|X|>a} X^2\,\mathrm d\mathbb  P - \int_{|X|<a} X^2\,\mathrm d\mathbb  P$$
Now with a sufficient choice of $a$ this becomes $1/2$. (As $X$ is absolute continuous, the expression takes every value between $1$ ($a=0$) and $-1$ ($a\to\infty$)).

But $X+Y$ is $2X$ for $|X|>a$ and $0$ else, so definitely not normally distributed.

Comment: The value for $a$ is approximately $1.10115$.

Comment: By the way this is also an example of how uncorrelated differs from independent. $X,Y$ are fully functionally dependent, but we can achieve any correlation, even correlation $0$ (which we get at about $a \approx 1.53817$).

Comment: Can someone help me find the derivative of $Cov(X, Y)$ with respect to $a$? I am interested in this, but when I tried to calculate it, I got 0, which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @neophyte_autodidact The integral in question is $\int_{-\infty}^{-a} x^2f(x)\,dx - \int_{-a}^a x^2f(x)\,dx + \int_a^\infty x^2f(x)\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} x^2f(x)\,dx - \int_{-a}^0 x^2f(x)\,dx + \int_0^a x^2f(x)\,dx + \int_a^\infty x^2f(x)\, dx$. The derivative wrt $a$ is by the fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule $-a^2f(-a) - (-(-a^2f(-a))) - a^2f(a) + (-a^2f(a)) = a^2(-f(-a)-f(-a)-f(a)-f(a)) = -2a^2(f(a)+f(-a)$ where $f$ is the density of $\mathcal N(0,1)$. As $f(-a)=f(a)$ this is $-4a^2f(a)$.

Comment: @neophyte_autodidact The rules to keep in mind: 1) $\frac{d}{da} \int_{x_0}^a f(x)\,dx = f(a)$, 2) $\frac{d}{da} \int^{x_0}_a f(x)\,dx = -f(a)$, 3) $\frac{d}{da} \int_{x_0}^{-a} f(x)\,dx = -f(a)$ and 4) $\frac{d}{da} \int^{x_0}_{-a} f(x)\,dx = -(-f(a)) = f(a)$

Comment: thanks so much! I'll double check this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @Lazy! I now get the same answer as you